# Dropdown navigation box

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to create a "dropdown on hover" navigation box from a navigation bar that I already have.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="brand" href="<?php echo $this->url('home') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Skeleton Application') ?></a>
            <div class="nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url('home') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Home') ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url('zfcuser') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('My Account') ?></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a
                                href="<?php echo $this->url('zfcuser/change-password') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Change Password') ?></a>

                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url('zfcuser/change-email') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Change Email') ?></a>

                        </ul></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What would the CSS for it look like? I've got something in my head, but it hasn't worked in practice.

Comment: Is there a reason your trying to do it purely in css?  Why not use something like jquery's built in functions?  show(), hide(), slideUp(), slideDown(), etc.

Comment: What about finding a suitable tutorial or similar structure and work on that? http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-dropdown-menu

Comment: @EricLeroy, there isn't but I don't want to be adding more JS to be page, though I could easily do it.

Comment: @jtheman, I'd much rather work with existing structures, rather than rewrite the navigation bar.

Comment: Somehow the html structure and classes looks similar to `bootstrap` framework. Do you want a expand-dropdown-on-hover effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want purely CSS, you can use the classic Son of Suckerfish: http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/

```
.nav-collapse, .nav-collapse ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-collapse a {
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
}

.nav-collapse li {
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
}

.nav-colapse li ul {
   position: absolute;
   width: 10em;
   left: -999em;
}

.nav-collapse li:hover ul {
   left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMh9U/) with very minimal CSS to get you the dropdown functionality.

You can see [this Github](https://github.com/jmeas/CSS3-Dropdown-With-Fade) for more features, like fading in and out.